# How to load secured PDF file by pdfbox, if I don't know the password?

Tags: java, pdfbox

PDDocument has the `load(InputStream input, String password)` method to load secured PDF file but I have no idea about the password.

This secured PDF file can be opened directly by Chrome or Adobe Acrobat, even it can be copied or edited. This confuses me.

Here is an example secured PDF file: https://bigdata-s3.wmcloud.com/jyresearchreport/juling/report/0000000000000jr9o2.pdf

My question is how this secured PDF file can be edited and how can it be loaded if I have no idea about password?

Comment: likely a bad PDF. If you had looked at your log files, you'd have noticed "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Actually the strings in a single object in that PDF are not encrypted at all (and so don't fulfill size restrictions): the strings in the **Info** dictionary. I'm not deep enough into PDF encryption to tell whether that is correct for appropriate settings or not. As Adobe Preflight (at least my old version 9.5) does not complain, though, it just might be correct...

Comment: It must be encrypted. /EncryptMetadata is false but this applies only to the /Metadata stream. PDF.js can show the file because they do parse on demand. Ghostscript hangs or takes very long. Microsoft Edge can display the file. Preflight should protest because encryption is not permitted in PDF/A files.

Comment: *"Preflight should protest because encryption is not permitted in PDF/A files."* - Well, I made it check for syntax errors, not for PDF/A conformance. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFBox 2.0.16 had sovled this problem.

Comment: Provide some more information to make it even clear